# Two SurfaceViews to accept Camera stream simultaneously

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, virtual-reality

I'm working on VR project for Android, and one of the tasks is to create two Surface Views which will handle simultaneous stream of Camera. After several attempts I found that only one Surface View can handle Camera stream, while another is idling.

Is there any way I can duplicate Camera stream and show it simultaneously in two separate Surface Views (One per eye)?

Thanks!